# Multi-purpose grilling apparatus possible for BBQ and shashlik possible?

Tags: grilling, barbecue, russian-cuisine

In Russia and Central Asia, they make *shashlik* on a *mangal*. A major difference is that the mangal does not have a grate that is the spits with meat pieces are directly exposed to the heat.

I've been looking for a while for sort of a multi-device, that is a BBQ grill where you could take the grate off and insert spits. If it has the smoker feature, even better.

[image: Post stamp showing a mangal]

Maybe anybody has seen something of this sort?

Comment: Every Turkish restaurant & takeaway near where I live - which is a lot, maybe 20 or so - has one or more of these. The grill section simply moves, slides or can be removed to leave skewer space. Trouble is, these are commercial kitchen ranges, not domestic or outdoor. Google found this domestic/outdoor version, which they call a [Turkish trough fire pit](https://www.crocus.co.uk/product/_/turkish-trough-fire-pit/classid.2000027849/)

Comment: @Tetsujin ah thank you! a good option; regarding the commercial range appliances you have seen, how big are they and do you think they are suitable for outdoor as well?